# Delete a row from Angular and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I need to delete a course from my course table. Front end is angular, back end is laravel. What am I doing wrong?

This is my delete course route:

Route::post('/course/delete/', 'AdminController@courseDelete');

This is my controller:

```
  public function courseDelete(){

 $data = Input::all();

    $course =Course::where('name', '=', $data["name"]);

    if($course->delete()) {

      Course::find($data["name"])->delete();

      return json_encode(array('success' => true));

    } else {

      return json_encode(array('success' => false, 'errors' => "Unable to remove course."));
    }
  }
```

This is my angular:

```
app.register.controller('adminDeleteCourse', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$location', 'pinesNotifications', '$route', 'SessionService', 'WebService', function($scope, $http, $modal, $location, pinesNotifications, $route, SessionService, WebService){

        var base_url = $("meta[name='base_url']").attr('content');
        $scope.courses = {};

    $scope.open = function(name, size) {
          var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

              $scope.items = items;
              $scope.ok = function() {

                $data = {
                  user_id: name
                };

                $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: base_url + '/course/getcourses',
                data : $data
                }).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                  if(data['success']) {

                    $route.reload();
                    pinesNotifications.notify({

                      title: 'Success',
                      text: 'Course successfully deleted.',
                      type: 'success',
                      hide: true
                    });

                  } else {

                    pinesNotifications.notify({

                      title: 'Error',
                      text: data['errors'],
                      type: 'error',
                      hide: true
                    });
                  }
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    $('#error').html('code: ' + status);
                    $('#alert').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hide');
                });

                $modalInstance.close();

              };

              }]);
```

This is my html

```
<a ng-click="open(course.name)" class="btn btn-brown btn-sm">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </panel>
        </div>
    </div>
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to delete course?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-brown" ng-click="ok()">Delete</button>
          <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>-->
      </div>
   </script>
```

I cannot delete the course from DB. What am I doing wrong?
I am pretty new to angular and laravel

Comment: What's the problem that you're facing with this?

Comment: cant delete course from course table

Answer (score 0):

In your courseDelete function, You have done a little mistake.

Add This line

```
$course =Course::where('name', '=', $data["name"])->first();
```

Instead of

```
$course =Course::where('name', '=', $data["name"]);
```

And You function look like:

```
public function courseDelete(){

   $data = Input::all();
   $course =Course::where('name', '=', $data["name"])->first();

   if($course->delete()) {

       return json_encode(array('success' => true));

   } else {

           return json_encode(array('success' => false, 'errors' => "Unable to remove course."));
   }
 }
```

Comment: in my scope.open is this correct?  $data = {
                  user_id: name
                };

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::find();
```

works with primary key.

so you need to pass id to fetch the row or you can do.

```
Model::where('column_name',$variable)->first();
```

For further details view : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent

Hope this helps you.

Comment: what should I pass in my scope.delete function?

Comment: public function courseDelete(){

   $data = Input::all();
   $course =Course::where('user_id', '=', $data["user_id"])->first();

   if($course->delete()) {

       Course::find($data["user_id"])->delete();
       return json_encode(array('success' => true));

   } else {

           return json_encode(array('success' => false, 'errors' => "Unable to remove course."));
   }
 }

Comment: also you are already deleting the row in if so now need to delete it again inside if

Comment: ya so pass that id